# How to get help for bash variables use from a command line?

Tags: bash, man, variable, documentation

Bash has some special or predefined variables, such as `$?` and `$#`.

How to know the meaning of those variables use build in command instead of searching online web pages?

I have try to use this:

```
help variables
```

But it didn't show those variables.

Comment: `man -P cat bash >bash.txt` then search this file for the special strings you are looking for. It is a little easier than going back and forth in the `man bash` output using `less` navigation capabilities. Also you can use `grep` etc. on the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bash man page. Open it with `man bash`.  Normally this is displayed by `less` (you can also read the man page for `less` with `man less`).

In `less` you can scroll down with `j`, up with `k`, quit with `q` and open a search prompt with `/`.  The section you want to search for is "Special Parameters".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bash info page. Open it with `info bash`. Note that some systems don't have the GNU `info` documentation system, or the `info` documentation for `bash` pre-installed, you may have to install a package for that.

In `info`, you can query the index of topics with `i` (completion is available). For instance, if you enter `$#`, you'll be taken directly to the definition of the `$#` variable.

To learn more about how to use `info`, try `info info`.

Answer (score 1):

Just execute this line:

```
LESS=+/'^ *Special Parameters' man bash
```

Comment: Learned a new way to use `$LESS`, thanks :)